# Nodejs Mongo query stream - CPU busy?

Tags: node.js, stream, mongoose, transform

We have a mongoosejs client which queries a large mongodb collection (about 10 million records) and pipes to to a transform stream. When we run this code, the node process takes 100% CPU and becomes busy, suggesting back pressure build up.  If we force a pause() of the read stream periodically, say, every 100 records, for 10 milliseconds, the CPU is not as busy.

I understand that the streams API is supposed to detect "back pressure" problems and handle them without developers calling pause() and resume(). Why is CPU becoming so busy with this code, and what's the best practice to develop a pipeline like this?

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
var util = require('util');
var zlib = require("zlib");

var Model = mongoose.model("xxx", someSchema)

var TransformStream = function() {
  return Transform.call(this, {
    objectMode: true
  });
};

util.inherits(TransformStream, Transform);

var transformChunk = function(chunk){
    //return transformed chunk here
}

TransformStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    var transformed = transformChunk(chunk);
    this.push(transformed, "utf-8");
    callback();
}

function main(){
    var zipStream = zlib.createGzip();
    var transformer = new TransformStream();
    var queryStream = Model.find(filter).stream();
    // outstream is a grid fs stream
    return queryStream.pipe(transformer).pipe(zipStream).pipe(outstream);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Backpressure would likely cause your transform method to block.  If the readable stream (mongo) is producing data fast enough, and the outstream storing fast enough, the CPU utilisation would be high if your transformer is doing anything significant.  Your delays are throttling the transformer, reducing CPU load.

It's not clear in the docs what relevance the return result of `push` has, its possible it can be ignored (but that might just consume memory in the event of back pressure from the downstream).

I found your question as a result of my own quest for an answer!